# How to copy elements from Fireworks to Photoshop with transparent background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

Always when I try to copy-paste something from Fireworks to Photoshop it gets a white background.

So often I end up saving the part I need as a seperate png-file with transparent background and then load that file into photoshop. But surely there is another way, isn't there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your shape goto  **EDit >> Copy as vectors** .

Open Photoshop and paste, Popup will Open, select **"shape layer"** and press OK

Comment: Finally I'm again in this kind of situation and so I tried your method, but I get (at pasting) "Could not complete the Paste command because the parser module cannot parse the clipboard." :( I'll try again with freshly started OS...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to save the Fireworks document as a .psd and open it on photoshop then copy whatever you want on the document you converted to a .psd

Answer (score -1):

Ungroup the vector in Fireworks and then copy it over. This seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I use fw2psd.com for conversion Fireworks PNG to PSD

Comment: Hi Ercort, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!